# How to Fade In and Insert Element then Fade Out and Remove Element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

**Description**

I have a `<button>` that, when clicked once, sets the class of a `<div>` element to "fade-in" and inserts the `<div>` element in the DOM. This visually fades in the `<div>` element after insertion into the DOM. When the button is clicked again, the button sets the class of the `<div>` element to "fade-out", waits with `setTimeout()`, and removes the `<div>` element from the DOM. This visually fades out the `<div>` element before removal from the DOM.

**Problem**

If the `<div>` element is in the DOM (after clicking once), and I proceed to click twice in rapid succession, then the `<div>` element fades out, then fades in, then gets removed from the DOM.

**Expected Result**

I would like the `<div>` element to, from the first click, fade out and be removed from the DOM, then, from the second click, fade in and be reinserted into the DOM. That is, the `<div>` element should both 1) be in the DOM and 2) appear visually after rapidly clicking twice when the button has already been pressed once. My assumption is that, because the second click happens before `setTimeout()` ends, the container is "inserted" (it already is inserted, though) into the DOM before the code within `setTimeout()` is executed (which removes the `<div>` from the DOM).

**How do I ensure that the code to reinsert the `<div>` element (occurring in the second mouse click event) is executed after the `setTimeout()` event (occurring in the first mouse click event)?**

**Code**

Attached below is a minimal reproducible example of my problem.

```js
const container = document.createElement("div");

let toggled = false;

const button = document.querySelector("button");
button.addEventListener("click", event => {
  toggled = !toggled;
  if (toggled) {
    container.setAttribute("class", "fade-in");
    button.parentElement.insertBefore(container, button.nextSibling);
  } else {
    container.setAttribute("class", "fade-out");
    setTimeout(() => {container.remove();}, 500)
  }
})
```

```css
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: black;
}

.fade-in {
    animation: fade-in 500ms linear;
}

@keyframes fade-in {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

.fade-out {
    animation: fade-out 500ms linear;
}

@keyframes fade-out {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../CSS/Test.css">
    <script src="../../JS/Test.js" async></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button> Fade In / Fade Out </button>
</body>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried using Promises, but none of my attempts have worked, unfortunately. Because I am new to Javascript, I am not sure whether I am using it wrong, or whether my approach has flaws.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a variable `inAnimation` that is set to `true` when an animation is triggered and set to `false` at the end of the animation using `setTimeout(f, animationDuration)` :

I also set the animation duration to `1000ms` to see the probleme more clearly.

Only need to change :

```js
const container = document.createElement("div");

let toggled = false;
let inAnimation = false; // is div currently animated

const button = document.querySelector("button");
button.addEventListener("click", event => {
    if(inAnimation) return; // test if there is no current animation

  if (!toggled) { 

    inAnimation = true;
    container.setAttribute("class", "fade-in");
    
    button.parentElement.insertBefore(container, button.nextSibling);
    setTimeout(() => {
        inAnimation = false; // end of animation
    }, 1000)

  } else if(!inAnimation) {
    inAnimation = true;
    container.setAttribute("class", "fade-out");

    setTimeout(() => {
        inAnimation = false; // end of animation
        container.remove();
    }, 1000)
  }

  toggled = !toggled; 
})
```

```css
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: black;
}

.fade-in {
    animation: fade-in 1000ms linear;
}

@keyframes fade-in {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

.fade-out {
    animation: fade-out 1000ms linear;
}

@keyframes fade-out {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../CSS/Test.css">
    <script src="../../JS/Test.js" async></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button> Fade In / Fade Out </button>
</body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why does it flicker at the end during fade out?

Comment: I don't see what you are talking about, it's work fine for me, the fade out is smooth

Comment: @nem0z Thank you so much for your great solution! Is it possible to change the animation such that 1) if the `<div>` is being faded in and the button is pressed again, the fade-in animation immediately stops and the fade-out animation is executed and 2) if the `<div>` is being faded out and the button is pressed again, the fade-out animation immediately stops and the fade-in animation is executed? In other words, can we change the animation while the animation is ongoing?

Answer (score 1):

I've accepted [@nem0z's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73133880/15936471), but wanted to provide an extended solution for my comment below his answer (how to change the animation while the animation is ongoing). The solution is to use `clearTimeout()` to prevent the code within `setTimeout()` from activating.

```js
const container = document.createElement("div");

let toggled = false;
let activeAnimation = false;

const button = document.querySelector("button");
button.addEventListener("click", event => {
  if (activeAnimation) {
    clearTimeout(timeoutID);
  }
  toggled = !toggled;
  activeAnimation = true;
  if (toggled) {
    container.setAttribute("class", "fade-in");
    button.parentElement.insertBefore(container, button.nextSibling);
    timeoutID = setTimeout(() => {
      activeAnimation = false;
    }, 500)
  } else {
    container.setAttribute("class", "fade-out");
    timeoutID = setTimeout(() => {
      container.remove();
      activeAnimation = false;
    }, 500)
  }
})
```

```css
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: black;
}

.fade-in {
    animation: fade-in 500ms linear;
}

@keyframes fade-in {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

.fade-out {
    animation: fade-out 500ms linear;
}

@keyframes fade-out {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../CSS/Test.css">
    <script src="../../JS/Test.js" async></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button> Fade In / Fade Out </button>
</body>
</body>
</html>
```